# Sunrace 10 Speed 11-46T cassette rear derailleur compatibility

Tags: cassette, derailleur-rear

I would like to know:

What rear derailleur (RD) was the "Sunrace 10 Speed 11-46T" designed to work with.

Is there a compatibility chart ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shimano 11 speed MTB rear derailleurs [can officially handle up to 46 cogs](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/deorext-m8000/RD-M8000-SGS.html) and can be run with 10 speed trigger shifters since the pull and ratio are almost the same. I used to run RD-M9000/SL-M980 combo successfully. So you can use those with the cassette in question.

There's also Archer/XShifter electric cable drivers, these allow to run any RD given it can handle 46t cog, like RD-M9100 or SRAM XX1 Eagle.

Comment: Thanks Klaster (that is useful)
I read similar reports about the "RD-M9000", 
Also the RD-M8000 (also stating 11spd 46T max , capacity 45T  if I remember correctly)
But its user collected empirical data!.

Comment: When companies started to manufacture range extender cogs, no RDs existed that officially supported 46t either. It was market following demand for wider range. Sunrace cassette is logical conclusion of 10s cassette with extender.

Comment: But I still don't understand how a global company can sell an engineering product (hack-it-product) without its intended optimal application/environment.

Comment: Nothing says a company can't sell a hack-it-product. There's a market for hack-it-products. Not every company should be as retrograde as, say, Shimano.

Comment: 1 I don't disagree at all .. .I actually like it., 
I love  hacky products above anything else.
I'm just disappointed of the lack documentation or guidance ...

Answer (score 3):

For the record.

I found this Sunrace RD catalog

http://www.sunrace.com/files/catalog/files/634/Specifications%20-%20Rear%20Derailleurs.pdf

On 2nd page there is 10-speed specs.

[image: rdMx10]